# Does circular reference between two objects requires the use of weakref?

Tags: python, python-3.x, weak-references

I am trying to implement something that works on the principle below:

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic = WeakValueDictionary({})
    def put_in(self, something):
        self.dic[something] = Thing(self, something)

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, container, name):
        self.container = container
        self.name = name

    def what_I_am(self):
        print("I am a thing called {}".format(self.name))

pot = Container()
pot.put_in('foo')
pot.dic['foo'].what_I_am()
```

But I get :

```
  File "C:/Users/jacques/ownCloud/dev/weakref.py", line 26, in <module>
    pot.dic['foo'].what_I_am()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'foo'
```

I understand that my implementation is not correct because `Thing` instance  gets GCed and deleted from the `WeakValueDictionary`.

Is there any way I could achieve something like this to prevent the circular reference between `Container` and `Thing` ?

Edit : If I change the code above for the one below, would it solve the circular reference issue ?

```
from weakref import proxy

class Container(dict):
    def put_in(self, something):
        self[something] = Thing(self)

class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = proxy(container)

    def what_is_it(self):
        print("I am a thing called {}".format(self))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try: #Look up the Thing instance first
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        except AttributeError: #Try to find the attribute in container
            return self.container.__getattribute__(name)

    def __format__(self, spec):
        (name,) = (key for key, val in self.container.items() if self == val)
        return name

pot = Container()
pot.location = 'Living room'
pot.put_in('foo')
pot['foo'].what_is_it()
print(pot['foo'].location)
```

Comment: Note that `Thing(self)` is called *before* `self.dic[thing] =` is executed.

Comment: Yes that's the issue I have with a normal dict. It's a bit like the thick and the egg. But I can solve it with `dic[thing]=None`

Comment: "`Thing` instance may get GC" well no, it **is** being garbage collected.  Hence the `KeyError`.

Comment: Sorry the phrasing is wrong. I understand the issue. I'm trying to prevent circular reference whilst keeping a dictionary structure.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Why does `Thing` need a reference to its container?

Comment: @Dunes: The `Thing` has a `__getattr__` method that looks up `container` if the attribute has not been found in the instance itself. I added this to the code to illustrate this.

Comment: Is it possible for a `Thing` to exist without a `Container`? What should happen to a `Thing` if its container no longer exists? It's easier to just use normal references and let the GC collect your `Thing` and `Container` when they drop out of scope.

Comment: @Dunes: No a `Thing` cannot exist without a `Container`. A `Thing` should be deleted if and only if its `container` is deleted. So if I understand correctly, I do not have to worry about the circular reference and I shall use normal reference to the `container`. Thanks for your help. I am not very comfortable with the garbage collection in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to worry about circular references. Python is fully capable of managing its own memory in this case. And will delete objects with circular references as and when necessary.

Your implemenation need only look like this:

```
class Container(dict):
    def put_in(self, something):
        self[something] = Thing(self, something)

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, container, name):
        self.container = container
        self.name = name

    def what_is_it(self):
        assert self.container[self.name] is self, "Thing stored under wrong name"
        print("I am a thing called {}".format(self.name))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # By the time __getattr__ is called, normal attribute access on Thing has
        # already failed. So, no need to check again. Go straight to checking the 
        # container
        try:
            return getattr(self.container, name)
        except AttributeError:
            # raise a fresh attribute error to make it clearer that the 
            # attribute was initially accessed on a Thing object
            raise AttributeError("'Thing' object has no attribute {!r}".format(name)) from e
```

A quick test to show you how things work:

```
c = Container()
c.put_in("test")
c.value = 0

# Attribute demonstration
c["test"].what_is_it()
t = c["test"]
print("name:", t.name) # get a Thing attribute
print("value:", t.value) # get a Container Attribute
c.name = "another name"
print("Thing name:" t.name) # gets Thing attrs in preference to Container attrs

# Garbage collection demonstration
import weakref
import gc

r = weakref.ref(c["test"])
del c, t
# no non-weak references to t exist anymore
print(r()) # but Thing object not deleted yet
# collecting circular references is non-trivial so Python does this infrequently

gc.collect() # force a collection
print(r()) # Thing object has now been deleted
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `__getattr__` !

Comment: The line `except AttributeError` misses the `as e` bit.

Comment: The at `as e` bit is not required as the exception is not used.Thus, there is no need to bind it to a local variable.

Comment: OK but then in the `raise` statement you have `from e` ?

Answer (score 2):

The very point of `WeakValueDictionary` is that its keys are automatically deleted once the objects are no longer in use.

Immediately after

```
self.dic[thing] = Thing(self)
```

there is no reference to the `Thing` object outside of the `WeakValueDictionary` anymore, so the behavior you are seeing is correct and expected.

If you expect the key to be reachable, replace `WeakValueDictionary` with the regular `dict`. Alternatively, make sure there is a reference to the thing, for instance by returning it or referencing it somewhere else.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Thanks, fixed. I wanted to make sure to clarify that it's not the `Thing` class, but looks like I inadvertently introduced even more confusion.